# Bad format of password when pulled out of DB

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, hash, bcrypt

I just wrote a simple script that asks a user for their username and password. It will then store the data to a data base. However, when I pull out the data (user wants to login) it shows the error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.`

I tried reformatting the password, but nothing helps. It does show me that the error is here:

```
line 27, in pull_from_db
    check_hash(password, hashed)
line 11, in check_hash
    if bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), hashed):
```

[This](https://gitlab.com/commRat/cryptography/-/blob/master/master%20login/master%20log.py) is the script.

Comment: Please add the code to question itself. Links to code are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a type mismatch like then when the query fails completely, returning null/nothing. So the null sure isn't a string, or a bytes-like object.

Use a external database client (for SQLite3, the command line client will do) to run the query as a standalone.

```
sqlite3 ex1
sqlite> SELECT * FROM master
```

It'll be a good idea to just see what you have in there, make sure that it was stored correctly.

For your put_to_db() function, I recommend renaming your parameters to username,hash, because you certainly **aren't** passing a password in there, and you don't want confusion about that.

Comment: I changed the name of variable, no impact on program. And inputs are stored like this:
('coma', b'$2b$16$tn7kBtMAFYLdScsIX3fSrOrlr8JX/EN7g93LuR4ubPekAGjFI5bRS')
('toto', b'$2b$16$7Cp.gDImk8mP6fRZx9Jbz.VBy3OKVQ.ce/kgqK7aJvo7zEIPlnZaK')
('season', b'$2b$16$5viLa0XfuG7vwkJsorLMiuK6SeUG9AOOOIulpxQupNdWLgKsF9ADO')

I will try to use external database, as you recommended. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Oh, yes, it wouldn't change the function, it's merely going to be more clear to YOU that you're getting a hash there, and not an actual password.

Comment: And It is stored as b'$2b$16$nEj1kUihMMKe6youUSS0kOqO4LT64o6IANOp0qBtWmxzW3N6nPVou' even when I don't use a b'' string. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Those look like properly hashed password... except for that leading b. And the quote marks shouldn't be there either. The hashing function is automatically adding a salt to the hash. It should look just like:

$2b$16$nEj1kUihMMKe6youUSS0kOqO4LT64o6IANOp0qBtWmxzW3N6nPVou

Comment: That b'' is there because I encoded that to utf-8. (password.encode('utf-8')). But if I remove that encoding I get error: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing.